# Save VBA Range.Find parameters before running to reset to defaults after

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have noticed that .Find (or ctrl + F) is one of the Excel features that defaults to the user's last set arguments/parameters. This is true when using find the user interface way:

```
Hit Ctrl + F
Expand the "Options >>"
Check off "Match entire cell contents"
close
```

The next time ctrl F is used, the default is set to Match entire cell contents, until changed.

Now I'm noticing this default is changed when using Range.Find in VBA:

```
Sub partialCTRLf()
' default ctrl+F back to partial cell content match
    Dim k As Boolean
    k = Range("A1").Find("something", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing
    k = Empty
End Sub
```

And then enter ctrl + F and you will see the settings change.

I am hoping to save the current default value of any .Find parameter, run the Range.Find line in vba, and then return the value to what it was before.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I don't believe they are exposed anywhere in the object model.

Comment: I resolved myself always explicitly setting parameters “What”, “LookIn” and “LookAt”.

Comment: @Rory so not possible? @ DisplayName Explicitly setting the parameters changes the user interface which is what I'm looking to resolve. I'm just wondering if I can keep things consistent for non-vba-savy users of my spreadsheets.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I seem to remember that in Word you could read the properties using the Dialogs collection, but not in Excel.